# Linux socket descriptor

Tags: linux, sockets

I am reading a tutorial on unix domain sockets at this [link](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html).

From searching on SO, I find socket descriptor is said to be the same as file descriptor and is said to point to an entry in the file descriptor table.

If this is true, I want to ask, where for an fd that would point to an inode of the file opened, does socket descriptor's entry also contain an inode of the socket file ?

Also in the sample code, after the server accepts a connection:

```
len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
s2 = accept(s, &remote, &len);
```

What would s2 point to (if socket descriptor is like fd, what entry would s2 point to in the file descriptor table) ?

Also, does the unix domain socket API just use open, read, and write to the socket file underneath ?

Answer (score 0):

I think "s2" is just another socket descriptor listening on the client side. Here's the man page for accept:

```
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html
```

Basically, what is happening (assuming I'm looking at the right code on Beej's site) is that you create a socket descriptor, which can accept connections. When a connection is actually made, you create another socket specific to that connection. [This page has another example](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/socketprogramming.html) that might make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will have a specific inode entry, as socket is also a resource from file-system it is part of devfs.

You can find socket associate fd details by `lsof` command